# Json serialize and deserialize dynamic object in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

Summary: I am required to submit a JSON request via C# where part of the payload changes based on certain business rules. I know all the possible structures, but have to use only the correct one in the request.

**Example 1**

```
{
"activity": {
        "referenceId": "",
            "data": {
                "rents": 0.0,
                "wages": 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

**Example 2**

```
{
"activity": {
        "referenceId": "",
            "data": {
                "transport": 0.0,
                "salaries": 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

**Example 3**

```
{
"activity": {
        "referenceId": "",
            "data": {
                "water": 0.0,
                "miscellaneous": 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

So, depending on some business rules, I have to change the parameters in "data". It's a bit more complex than just two property names, but I think the answer to this question as asked will be sufficient.

I have set up POCO's as per usual, but have no idea how to get them to work within this requirement.

I had the idea to create a "master" Data object and somehow only pass along the properties required, but I'm stumped at that point.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Activity activity { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
    public string referenceId { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data //Inheriting from this master won't work.
{
    public float water { get; set; }
    public float miscellaneous { get; set; }
    public float transport { get; set; }
    public float salaries { get; set; }
    public float rents { get; set; }
    public float wages { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please describe some examples of those different structures

Comment: example 1,2,3 demonstrate the different structures. basically different property names

Comment: Always you will have only two properties in the "data" object?

Comment: No, it will vary widely

Comment: So a dictionary would not be a good solution. Why don't you use generic Data? Activity will have two properties, RefernceId, and Data<T>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use null property ignore functionality for all properties. Like this:

```
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
public float water { get; set; }
```

This attribute remove null data from your object.

Comment: Hmmm. This is a nice solution for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a lot of different solutions to handle JSON's like this, but in long term the best thing is simple Dictionary:

```
class Root
{
  public Activity Activity { get; set; }
}

class Activity
{
  public string ReferenceId { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, float> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can just map those object to whatever you want.

You can also read about [converters and polimorphic deserialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#support-polymorphic-deserialization), but it's not so easy. You have to manually detect discriminator (some unique field existing in one type) and... still, do it manually, in converter.

Comment: That sounds like a step in the right direction.